# CSS 3 Column fluid-fixed-fluid

Tags: css

I am trying to make a three column design with two fluid sidebars and one fixed center.   When the browser width changes I want the center to remain and the sidebars' width to diminish. Thanks

Comment: Okay, what is the question? What do you need help with specifically? What have you done so far?

Comment: So I really want a continuous graphic. But for it to work I need(from left to right) a fluid div with one part of the image, a fixed width div that is centered on the page, and then another fluid div on the right with the rest of the image. So I have it 'working', but its no where near a decent solution...I am using cloned images and other weird stuff.  So I need the basic structure and css.

Answer (score 3):

this example is specific to your requirements: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-36-fluid-fixed-fluid/  --- although you will need to adjust the widths a little probably
hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I messed around with it, but didn't get anywhere. It would be that fluid container on both sides with the fixed width div being centered.